# Expo.Notifications.addListener() is not firing (iOS standalone App)

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, expo

I am trying to use Expo.Notifictions.addListener in my component (on iOS standalone build), but it doesn't fire although notifications are successfully received.

addListener() is placed inside `componentDidMount()` function.

```
Expo.Notifications.addListener(this.handleNotification);

handleNotification = () => {
  this.setState({
    something: 3,
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "... but it doesn't fire although notifications are successfully received."?

You mean that when the app is foregrounded the push notification's not shown?


Also, what's the SDK version you're using?

Comment: @BrunoEduardoDAngelodeOlive Yes, I mean that the notification is sent to my device, but the listener is not reacting when the app is foregrounded. I'm using the version: "28.0.0".

Comment: I use the same version in my app and the listener fires but I don't see any notifications when the app is in the foreground (code's executed though). Have you tried checking if that's the same for you? Also, seems like older  SDKs might be bugged (https://forums.expo.io/t/ios-push-notifications-not-work-while-app-is-open-and-foregrounded/9473/2) try updating to v32.0.0 and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: If the application is running in the foreground, iOS won't show a notification banner/alert. That's by design (Android for example shows notification in the status bar on the top, and that's not the case by iOS). That's why I need the listener, to render the component or to inform the user that the notification came. If your listener is working, can you please put your code example? I also think that the problem is older SDK.

Comment: Sorry but I can't, it's code for the proprietary app I develop at work. I'm not at home right now, but I'll try to get you a working iOS example ASAP ok?

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding callback into ur addListener function.

```
componentDidMount(){
    Notifications.addListener(notification => {
      console.log(notification);  
    });
}
```